Deserialize class using jackson from external dependency
I want to deserialize a class that comes from an external dependency using jackson and have below constraints.

I cannot add any annotations to the class that is to be deserialized as it comes from an external dependency and not editable.
I checked JacksonMixInAnnotations (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) however that needs writing a custom object mapper. But I have around 40 dependencies and writing a custom object mapper for each of them seems like a messy option.
I looked into https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2852 where .setConstructorDetector(ConstructorDetector.PROPERTIES) is recommended. I need to try this out.

Has anyone solved this problem before? What is the best recommendation here?
Thank you.

Are you sure you need a separate object mapper for each class? The documentation is not very clear on this point, but I’m pretty sure you can add multiple mix-ins for different classes to the same object mapper. Mix-ins are the tool created for this job.

even if that is the case, for every such class, I will need to add a mix-in, which makes my code lengthy and not so generic.

Have you tried your third option yet? It’s not very clear what your question is asking for, at least to me. Jackson is able to automatically deserialize some classes, if they follow certain conventions. In other cases needs metadata to instruct it how to deserialize them. There aren’t enough details in the question for someone to identify which of these cases you have.
